# "Operation timed out" when ssh to my MAC after the server is up for sometime

Tags: macos, ssh

I am running macOS Big Sur and I started the remote login. Immediately after the service is up, everything works fine. However, after some random period, the server refuses to accept new ssh connections any more. Any connection to it receive an "Operation timed out" error, either from localhost or another computer from local intranet or internet. Interestingly, the existing connection still works fine. It should not be a firewall issue as the firewall has been disabled. I almost need to restart the service every day which is very annoying. Any recommendations about what could introduce this issue or where to debug this issue?
-Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I am wondering if this is a power saving feature that is stopping you from access the Mac remotely?  Try disabling sleep?

Comment: Thanks, will try.

Comment: As a follow-up, I realized that I do not have the power saving feature enabled. So this should not be the issue.